# Install Windows 10 and Ubuntu HDD and SSD

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a desktop computer with Windows 10 and a 750GB HDD. I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, so I think I'll need a more disk space. I want to buy  a 200~300 GB SSD, and put in it the OS (Windows and Linux) files and a few more things.

Can I use both an HDD and an SSD? Will it be the best option in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both hard drive and SSD - it sounds fairly practical to have a dual boot Windows and Linux OS (and there swap files) on the SSD, and then conver the 750 gig hard drive to a data partition.

If you are going to do this, you will need to decide the format for the hard drive - Windows can't easily read most Linux native formats, and there are drawbacks to using Windows file formats under Linux.  (Depending on the OS, you probably want to run NTFS or EXFAT so the hdd is visible from both OS's)

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) works *quite* well with 60--100 GB space on the primary drive, so there should not be a necessity to buy a new drive.

Further, for convenience and to save drive space, common files can be shared by both Linux and Windows. For example, music, photos, videos, Thunderbird email folders and ebooks (e.g. Calibre depository) can be left on the Windows NTFS partition, and corresponding Linux applications can point to them. Because Windows does not work well with the ext*n* disk format, don't move any shared resource to the Linux partition.

However, if you want the extra speed a SSD offers, you might clone the HDD to it and thoroughly test it as a dual boot drive. After you're comfortable that the SSD works well alone, then use the old HDD for the predefined MS Music, Pictures and Video folders and other shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

[partitions windows-linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcN83.png)

My configuration from 1 Tb ( see image from program gparted Linux):

1. Defragment and resize partition C ( only from Windows !!)
2. Create partition D NTFS visible for Windows and Linux
3. Install version Linux desired and repartition:

   - ext4: Partition System Linux
   - ext4: OPTIONAL: Partition /home (data exclusive for Linux not visible       from Windows)
   - swap:linux memory exchange

Note: if more than 4 primary partitions are desired to create a logical containing 4 primary (see picture)

Create boot in sda of Windows (C) (it is done automatically when you install Linux)

Comment: clone a hard drive with Windows can give problems (Windows is not genuine) in certain installations